# How should I install JDateChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

I've discover this JDateChooser from searching how to use Item Combobox at Java Swing.  Do you know how to install this?

Here is the link [JDateChooser](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/JavaDateChooserComboBox.htm)

I can't find any instructions on how to install it..

Can you share some instructions on how to install it... thanks in advance v(^_^)v

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's very simple.

Download the [Toedter](http://toedter.com/software/) jcalendar-1.4.jar (also [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.toedter/jcalendar) will locate it)
If you are using Netbeans you can create an new bean and add the Toedter beans to your Palette Manager:

[image]

This gives you the capability to drag and drop these anywhere you like:

[image]

If you drag and drop the bean somewhere, the code that is generated looks like here:

```
jDateChooser1 = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
jDateChooser1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
jDateChooser1.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

You can then use the beans like this:

```
 java.sql.Date di = rs.getDate("edate");
 jDateChooser1.setDate(di);
```

or

```
java.util.Date jud =  jDateChooser1.getDate();
long t = jud.getTime();
java.sql.Date sqd = new java.sql.Date(t);
rs.updateDate("edate", sqd);
```

or like this if you want to format the Date:

```
java.util.Date jud =  jDateChooser1.getDate();
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
jLabel1.setText(sdf.format(jud));
```

Comment: needs to download Netbeans first, but nice answer.

Comment: yeah, i think that for Swing Netbeans is "The Tool"... :-)

Comment: Hi again Costis Aivalis... I have a little problem again.. jDateChooser prints something like this: Thu Jun 16 16:13:03 CST 2011 but what I only need is the Date like something like: June 16, 2011.  How should capture the date with MMM dd, YYYY format? thanks again.. :) o by the way... im using this jDateChooser1.getDate() to capture the input thanks again ^_^

Comment: You must use SimpleDateFormat with TimeZone and Date in order to generate the display Strings the way you need. I have just updated the answer to include this for U...

Comment: The links are not working, here is the updated link for the jcalendar-1.4.jar download: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjcalendar14jar.htm

Comment: Thank you Sanlyn. The first link (https://toedter.com/software/) is OK. Seems that jarfinder retired. So i updated the second link to maven repository, which always works.

Answer (score 4):

Add the sources to yours and use the classes like in `JCalendarDemo.java`